# How do you display Google Place Photos using URL in SwiftUI?

Tags: swift, uiimage, google-places-api, swiftui, combine

So, I'm trying to display photos in SwiftUI using photo_references provided by Google's Places API, but am having an issue I cant seem to solve.

From what I understand, one needs to create a URL using a photo reference and API key in order to access Google place photos. [Info here](https://developers.google.com/places/web-service/photos)

I'm currently able to correctly request all the necessary information from google and create the correct URL to get specific photos. But when I try to display the returned image using the URL, my application wont show the image and instead shows my placeholder/backup option in case the google images don't load.

-

More code details are listed below:

I modeled my code after the tutorial [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=1IlUBHvgY8Q)

Example url i've created and passed in:
(excludes my api key for this question)

```
https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/photo?maxwidth=200&photoreference=CnRtAAAATLZNl354RwP_9UKbQ_5Psy40texXePv4oAlgP4qNEkdIrkyse7rPXYGd9D_Uj1rVsQdWT4oRz4QrYAJNpFX7rzqqMlZw2h2E2y5IKMUZ7ouD_SlcHxYq1yL4KbKUv3qtWgTK0A6QbGh87GB3sscrHRIQiG2RrmU_jF4tENr9wGS_YxoUSSDrYjWmrNfeEHSGSc3FyhNLlBU&key=YOUR_API_KEY
```

**ImageViewWidget.view** - Here is the View that handles requesting and displaying Google Place Photos:

```
import SwiftUI
import Foundation
import Combine


class ImageLoader: ObservableObject {
    var didChange = PassthroughSubject<Data, Never>()

    var data = Data() {
        didSet {
            didChange.send(data)
        }
    }

    init(imageUrl: String) {
        // implementation
        guard let url = URL(string: imageUrl) else { return }
        URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: url) { (data, _, _) in
            guard let data = data else { return }

            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                self.data = data
                print("imageLoader.data - ", data)
            }
        }.resume()
    }
}


struct ImageViewWidget: View {

    @ObservedObject var imageLoader: ImageLoader

    init(imageUrl: String) {
        imageLoader = ImageLoader(imageUrl: imageUrl)
        print("imageUrl - ", imageUrl)
    }

    var body: some View {
        Image(uiImage: (imageLoader.data.count == 0) ? UIImage(named: "turtlerock")! : UIImage(data: imageLoader.data)!)
            .resizable()
            .frame(width: 55, height: 55)
            .cornerRadius(6)
    }
}
```

**MarkerInfoWindow.view** - And here is the file/view in my application that calls **ImageViewWidget.view**:

```
import SwiftUI
import UIKit


struct MarkerInfoWindow: View {


    var placedata: [String: Any]
    var placetypedata: [String]


    var body: some View {

        HStack {
            Text("4")
                    VStack(alignment: .leading) {
                        HStack {
//This is where i call ImageViewWidget vvv
                            ImageViewWidget(imageUrl: placedata["photo_reference"] as! String)

                            VStack(alignment: .leading) {
                                HStack {
                                    Text(placedata["name"] as! String)
                                        .font(.system(size: 16))
                                        .bold()
                                    Spacer()
                                    Text("10am-10pm")
                                    .font(.system(size: 12))
                                }
                                HStack {
                                    Text("⭐ \(placedata["rating"] as! String)")
                                        .font(.system(size: 14))
                                        .foregroundColor(Color(UIColor.systemYellow))
                                    Text("$ \(placedata["price_level"]! as! String)")
                                        .font(.system(size: 14))
                                        .foregroundColor(Color(UIColor.systemGreen))
                                }
                                HStack {
                                Text(placetypedata[0])
                                    .font(.system(size: 14))
                                }
                            }
                            Spacer()

                        }

                    }
                    Spacer()

                }


    }

}
```

I've verified the url im passing in is correct becsause when I paste it into my browser, the images appear properly. But when I run my app it keeps displaying the 'turtlerock' image defined at the bottom of the **MarkerInfoWindow.view** file above instead of the one i'm requesting. So that being said,

**Does anyone know why my application isn't displaying the Google Place Photos I'm requesting, and displaying my fail safe option instead?**

EDIT: 
I think the 'turtlerock' image is showing up because my imageLoader.data is initially empty, but ImageViewWidget doesn't update to the proper image because it isn't picking up changes to imageLoader.data. I could be wrong but I hope someone who is more experienced finds this useful in helping find an answer to this

Comment: Your code is not runnable at my side, but I assume the origin is in your `ObservableObject`... as you don't use @Published (that is preferable) try after `didChange.send(data)` add `self.objectWillChange.send()`

Comment: How could I use @Published in the preferred way? And did you mean placing self.objectWillChange.send() outside or inside of didSet { }? Thank you for the help btw